# Editing existing SBT project folder in Eclipse without copying it to workspace

Tags: scala, eclipse, emacs, import

I have an existing SBT project which I'm primarily working on using Emacs with [Ensime](http://aemoncannon.github.io/ensime/); I would like to keep it that way. However, I would also, occasionally, like to edit and refactor (and if possible, compile and run) the same project in [Eclipse Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org).

I don't seem to be able to go about doing that without the project folder being copied to a workspace. I've tried both **[Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace]** as well as **[Import -> File System]** to no avail—both seem to cause a copy to be made.

If it's something simple and obvious, I apologize; I'm quite a beginner with Eclipse. Also, I did ask Google, but couldn't find anything that is similar enough—usually it's just people moving away from one editor/IDE to Eclipse, so they don't care about the code being copied in the import process.

**P.S.** I tried opening the containing folder of the existing project as the workspace, but after that, the workspace is still empty.

**P.P.S.** One might ask, why not just make the Eclipse workspace the primary location of the project and then edit it with Emacs there, but that would mean changing my existing "standard" layout, or moving just one project out to a dedicated Eclipse workspace or smth. So I think it would be nice to just edit an existing folder with Eclipse without having to move or copy it.

Comment: on the import dialog before entering "finished" you can disable the option "copy to workspace", did you see that?

Comment: Didn't feel like programming related—is it? I was afraid it would be marked as Off-Topic.

Comment: @sschaef: ah, you mean with **[Existing Projects into Workspace]**... but the problem is that it's not an existing Eclipse project, so it doesn't let me import it that way at all: the **[Finish]** button is disabled and the **Projects** list box is empty.

Comment: @ErikAllik - questions about programming tools are explicitly mentioned as being on topic on Stack Overflow. As you've found your answer there's no point in migrating this question, but it's something to bear in mind for the future.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisF, I'd never noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it; it was easier than I'd thought: Just create a new (Scala) project with the path of the existing project (uncheck **[Use default location]**), and it seems to Just Work.